# Chrome and Firefox list-style-image

Tags: javascript, css, parsing, dom, cross-browser

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");               
doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("ul"));
doc.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style["listStyle"] = "square inside url('image.png')";
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style["listStyleImage"]);
```

In Internet Explorer, I get:

```
url("image.png")
```

However, on Firefox (sometimes) and Chrome, I get:

```
url()
```

Any advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why do you have to handle it this way. But if you use the full url to the image it should work:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");               
doc.body.appendChild(doc.createElement("ul"));
doc.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style["listStyle"] = "square inside url(http://www.example.com/image.png)";
console.log(doc.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].style["listStyleImage"]);
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the Browser's CSSOM to parse CSS properties.